# Relay compiler throws syntax error: Unexpected "$" when running in Github Action

Tags: graphql, github-actions, relay

I am using Relay (and Hasura) and hence are required to compile my code ahead of time using the `relay-compiler`. I can compile the code fine on my local machine, however it always fails when in Github Actions.

Here is the section of my `yml` file where is breaks:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
# other steps
- name: Download GraphQL Schema
  run: SECRET=$SECRET ENDPOINT=$ENDPOINT yarn run get-schema
  env:
    SECRET: ${{ secrets.hasura_admin_secret }}
    ENDPOINT: ${{ secrets.graphql_endpoint }}
- name: Test Compile Relay
  run: yarn run relay <<< this fails
- name: Test build
  run: yarn run build
```

And here are those scripts in my `package.json`.

```
"start": "yarn run compile-css && react-scripts start",
"build": "yarn run build-compile-css && react-scripts build",
"get-schema": "yarn run get-graphql-schema -h \"x-hasura-admin-secret=$SECRET\" $ENDPOINT > schema.graphql",
"relay": "yarn run relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src src",
```

It fails with the error:

```
$ /home/runner/work/<company-name>/<app-name>/node_modules/.bin/relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src src
Writing js
ERROR:
Syntax Error: Unexpected "$".
```

I have verified that schema is downloaded correctly and the paths to the schema and src folder are correct.

Is there specific config or arguments I need to pass to get this working in a CI environment?

---

*Update*

After more testing, I have found that the downloaded file from get-graphql-schema is somehow not correct. The issue is not there if I commit the schema and use this instead of downloading it.

I have the understanding it is bad practice to upload `graphql.schema` files, is this the case? If so are there are special arguments or set up required to get schema files working correctly in Github Actions?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find that when running the `get-graphql-schema` it Github Actions it add the following line as the first line of the file. I can remove this via an additional script.

schema.graphql

```
$ /home/runner/work/<company-name>/<app-name>/node_modules/.bin/relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src src
schema {
  query: query_root
  mutation: mutation_root
  subscription: subscription_root
}
...
```

I am unsure though why running this command in github actions will copy the first line.